# Bootstrap, checkbox is not uncheck when clicked if the checkbox is checked on page load

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

When page load, a checked box does not uncheck if clicked. I have to click it twice so that it can uncheck. How to solve this problem?

My reference code can be found [here in codepen](https://codepen.io/bseth99/pen/fboKH?editors=1111).

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="button-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" checked />&nbsp;Option 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option2" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option3" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option4" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option5" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option6" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 6</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var options = [];

$('.dropdown-menu a').on('click', function (event) {

    var $target = $(event.currentTarget),
        val = $target.attr('data-value'),
        $inp = $target.find('input'),
        idx;

    if ((idx = options.indexOf(val)) > -1) {
        options.splice(idx, 1);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $inp.prop('checked', false)
        }, 0);
    } else {
        options.push(val);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $inp.prop('checked', true)
        }, 0);
    }

    $(event.target).blur();

    console.log(options);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: seems fine to me

Comment: copy my html part, theres a "checked" for option 1, you try to click it once, it wont uncheck, u have to click it twice to uncheck it

Comment: nothing is checked in there by default. 
Moreover, you are doing a lot in there. What is the purpose of saving the ids in an array ?

Comment: the issue is because you are pragmatically checking and unchecking the inputs and by default when something is checked, its id is not in the array so your code marks it as checked again. gettin it  ?

Comment: the codepen i found is only for my reference, the real one is the one that i pasted in my question....i still dont get it, how to solve it

Comment: I don't get what are you trying to do with this but replace`$inp.prop( 'checked', false )` and `$inp.prop( 'checked', true )` with `$inp.prop( 'checked', !$inp.prop("checked") )`

Comment: but if i change this, the console seems weird because it reads the one i uncheck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are giving `checked` for `option1`, you are not adding it into the `options` array. The `options` array is empty at the beginning causing the double clicking issue.

If you are going to use checked then add `"option1"` to the `options` array and it will work fine.

Comment: how do I add it in the `options` array on page loads? because some of the options is checked on a new page

Comment: Maybe use $( document ).ready() and hardcode the values or use an ajax call to get the checked values from server.